# Text area with vertical scroll bar Java FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am trying to define a TextArea with a vertical scroll in my .fxml file. But, unfortunately, in-spite of trying various options, I only get a horizontal scroll bar. I intend to put a text consisting of 3 paragraphs in there.

```
            <TextArea fx:id="legalproseTextArea" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" style="overflow:scroll" text="“Transaction” includes a payment, purchase, sale, loan, pledge, gift, transfer, or delivery, and with respect to a financial institution includes a deposit, withdrawal, transfer between accounts, exchange of currency, loan, extension of credit, purchase or sale of any stock, bond, certificate of deposit, or other monetary instrument, use of a safe deposit box, or any other payment, transfer, or delivery by, through, or to a financial institution, by whatever means effected, except that “transaction” shall not include payments to attorneys for legal services." visible="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="19" />
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: The scroll bar will appear automatically if the text occupies more height than the text area. All your text is on a single line; if you want it to wrap, then just add `wrapText="true"`.

Comment: @James_D Thanks a lot. This solution helped.